# C# Prevent resizing of both splitcontainer panels

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

I have a SplitContainer and was wondering how I would go about setting a static size for both panels and prevent the user from having the ability to resize the panels.  Would FixedPanel be the solution?  From what I read, I don't think it is.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you are just looking for the "IsSplitterFixed" property.

Comment: And make sure the panel isn't docked or anchored (bottom/right) to a resizable container.

Answer (score 10):

The title of this question is **misleading**. There are *more than one* correct answers that satisfy the *title* of this question, in spite of the chosen answer.

For clarification:

`FixedPanel` is what you're looking for to have one panel keep its size when resizing the SplitContainer. According to the description in the Properties window:

> **FixedPanel**
>
> Indicates that a particular SplitContainer's Panel should remain fixed in size during resize events

`IsSplitterFixed` is just a way to *temporarily* prevent the user from *moving* the splitter. The panels still resize in proportion to the SplitContainer's size.

Answer (score 4):

I am really curious why you would want to use split container if you don't want the user to resize it

However in case you want to prevent one of the panels from auto-resizing with the parent container

It is the "Fixed panel" property of Split container.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow the user to resize the panels, do not use an SplitContainer.

Simply use panels, and add a 2px width panel to simulate the separator.

- PanelContainer -> Will contain PanelA, PanelB and PanelC
- PanelA (left panel) -> Dock it to left
- PanelB (separator) -> setup to have 2px width
- PanelC (right panel) -> Dock it to fill

Then, you can change the size of the panels as you want in design mode, and the user will not be able to resize the panels.